# Laravel carbon IF statement

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade, php-carbon

I try to create DOM with blade and carbon if auction is live by this way:

```
@if ( {{(Carbon\Carbon::now()) < ($article->auction_end)}} )
  <div class="col-md-3 leftEdge">
    <p>Auction is ACTIVE</p>
  </div>
@endif
```

but I get error:

> FatalErrorException in e91f1d7e7c19547ed6cb12e22b4988e0 line 21:
>       syntax error, unexpected '<'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
@if (Carbon\Carbon::now() < $article->auction_end)
<div class="col-md-3 leftEdge">
<p>Auction is ACTIVE</p>
</div>
@endif
```

You should not use `{{` in control statements

In addition to compare dates in valid way, you should also change comparison using Carbon lte operator, so finnaly it should look like this:

```
@if (Carbon\Carbon::now()->lte(Carbon\Carbon::parse($article->auction_end)))
<div class="col-md-3 leftEdge">
<p>Auction is ACTIVE</p>
</div>
@endif
```

Comment: Ok, thats right but I dont understand why both time I get Auction is Closed when I have two different time from now() - one in past one in future and I both times get: Auction is Closed with : @ if ( $article->auction_end > \Carbon\Carbon::now() )
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <p>Auction is ACTIVE</p>
                        </div>
                            @ else
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <p>Auction is Closed</p>
                            </div>
                        @endif

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness Please verify whether it will work when you use `@if (Carbon\Carbon::now()->lte($article->auction_end))` result will be as expected

Comment: no, give me error: Argument 1 passed to Carbon\Carbon::lte() must be an instance of Carbon\Carbon, string given, called in C:\wamp\www\learn5\storage\framework\views\e91f1d7e7c19547ed6cb12e22b4988e0 on line 21 and defined (View: C:\wamp\www\learn5\resources\views\articles\index.blade.php)

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness Is `auction_end` datetime or timestamp directly from database? If so, try `@if (Carbon\Carbon::now()->lte(Carbon\Carbon::parse($article->auction_end)))`

Answer (score 1):

It seem's like you're using curly brackets "{{" and "}}" inside the if statement. These are only nessecary if you try to echo a variable outside of an @ function like @if. remove the brackets and it should work^^

for further reference, have a look at the official docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates